# Movie function in python

Tags: python, class, video

I was trying to write a function in python to print out all the overlapping movie interests.
I wanted to write this program as a little classes and objects exercise. So this is what it looks like, right now:

```py
def main():
    class Person:
        def __init__(self, Film):
            self.Film = Film

        like_it = "Film" , "Movie"
        def likes(self, Film):
            if (Film in like_it):
                return Film
            else:
                print("no movies in common")


    Person1 = Person("Movie")
    print(Person1.likes)
```

I wanted to initialize different People as objects in the class "Person". The Program doesn't see any mistakes, but prints nothing. What is wrong here? Where should I look?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing Film as an argument in the `likes` method.

**Working with Classes**

```py
class Person:
        def __init__(self, Film):
            self.Film = Film

        like_it = "Film" , "Movie"
        def likes(self):
            if (self.film in like_it):
                return self.film
            else:
                return "no movies in common" #we are returning string instead of printing
Person1 = Person("Movie")
print(Person1.likes()) #likes is a method that has to be called
```

References:

- [Object Oriented Programming with python](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/)

Further Reading:

- [Converting methods to property](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)